# Azure Backend - Code First Migration - CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

When I create a new table for my Azure Backend using Code First Migration, the script looks like

CREATE TABLE(...)
CREATE TRIGGER ...
...
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] ...

And it always fails saying "CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement".
I have workarounds to make it work however I'd like to understand if this is a bug with Code First Migration or me not using it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It says that your script must begin by "CREATE TRIGGER". In SQL Management studio, you would put a "GO" just before your CREATE TRIGGER. "GO" is not a real T-SQL command, it's like a string split of your script.

If your script in is a SQL file, put a "GO" and do some thing like :

```
foreach (var script in fullScript.Split(new[] { "GO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    _dbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
}
```

Comment: I could however do something similar to what you suggest such as replacing "create trigger" with "go create trigger". But what I'm really after is why Code First not doing it properly.